# Perforce: Integrate all revisions at once, but with the same result as integrating the revisions one by one?

Tags: automation, perforce, perforce-integrate

### Situation:

1. *test/...* containing *a.txt* was branched into *test2/...*
2. *test/a.txt* was deleted, and then re-added and edited
3. Now I'd like to integrate all revisions from *test/...* to *test2/...*.

[image: revision graph]

In my actual use case, there can be many files like *a.txt*

### What I've tried:

I've tried three methods:

**Method 1** - Integrating all revisions results in a conflict as it thinks that test/a.txt#3 is a new, unrelated file:

```
>p4 integrate //depot/test/... //depot/test2/...
//depot/test2/a.txt#1 - integrate from //depot/test/a.txt#3,#4

>p4 resolve -as
c:\depot\test2\a.txt - merging //depot/test/a.txt#3,#4
Diff chunks: 0 yours + 0 theirs + 0 both + 1 conflicting
```

**Method 2** - Integrating using the `p4 integrate -Di` works in isolation, but I'm trying to make this part of an automated process that will integrate thousands of files at once. Since [the -Di flag can't be used in all cases](https://community.perforce.com/s/article/15287), it would at minimum need to check the file history to see if the file was moved/renamed, and starts to get very messy.

**Method 3** - Integrating one revision at a time works, but only if I submit each revision separately. Otherwise multiple integrations on the same file can't be opened simultaneously. This is slow if I have hundreds of changelists to integrate, and results in unnecessary integrate changes in the file history.

```
>p4 integrate //depot/test/a.txt#2 //depot/test2/a.txt
//depot/test2/a.txt#1 - delete from //depot/test/a.txt#2

>p4 integrate //depot/test/a.txt#3 //depot/test2/a.txt
//depot/test2/a.txt - can't integrate (already opened for delete)
```

### Question:

Method 3 has the result I want (no conflicts), but can I achieve that while integrating all revisions in one go as in Method 1?

Comment: What do you want to do if `test2` has been edited?

Comment: Also -- why do you have thousands of files in this state?  If there was some sort of incident where a bunch of files were deleted and then re-added without connecting history (i.e. they were copied in manually instead of being restored with `p4 sync` or `p4 undo`) it might be worth going back and surgically obliterating those changelists to keep this from being a recurring issue.

Comment: @Samwise good questions - if test2 has been edited, then there's a real conflict that couldn't be automatically resolved even if the changelists were integrated one by one, so we accept that it will need to be resolved manually. In our specific case it doesn't happen very often because users don't typically edit the same files simultaneously on multiple branches.

Comment: @Samwise As to why a lot of files can end up in this state, one example is that the user deletes a directory, but keeps a backup. Later on (maybe the same day), the user decides they actually wanted to keep those files so they restore it from their backup and re-add it. Another case is that the files can be automatically generated by some other app. Not all the users are very technical, so rather than trying to get all of them to use p4 undo consistently, it's easier to make things "just work", no matter which method they use.

Comment: TBH I might solve this by having a trigger at submit time that checks to see if they're re-adding a manual copy of an older revision, and then re-opens it as a copy from that older revision.  I don't think there's an `integrate` incantation that handles this the way you want because integrate doesn't look at the content, and it doesn't want to do a three-way merge if there's no base -- but if the metadata records that the later variant of the file is a copy of the older one (which is what happens if you use p4 commands to restore a deleted file) then integrate can follow those to find a base.